# Serial number issue in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have orders and order details table as shown as below:

### OrderDetails

```
Order_ID   int 
Order_Code varchar(10)
Product Name   varchar(50)
Qty     Int
SeqNO   varchar(10)
```

Below are the sample records

```
10001    OC   Ottoman   10  Null
10002    OC   Ottoman   3   Null  
10003    OC   Ottoman   2   Null
10004    OC   Ottoman   2   Null
```

Is there anyway I can update the SeqNo column with 1, 1A,1B,1C if the Order_Code is same else it should increment by one.

for example

```
10001    OC   Ottoman   10  Null
10002    OD   Ottoman   3   Null  
10003    OE   Ottoman   2   Null
10004    OF   Ottoman   2   Null
```

this one should be 1,2,3,4

Please help

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to match up with your example.  You ask how to generate a value for the `SeqNo` column, but your example shows values being changed in the `Order_Code` column, and it isn't really clear how the sequence works (why does it start at `0C`?)  Please edit with a clarification of this.

Comment: Aaronaught, If there are 5 orders with order code OC then I need to update the SeqNo column with values 1,1A,1B,1C,1D
The order_code is a varchar field and it is not zero it is letter O

Comment: Why would you need to UPDATE the table at all?  You can derive that information from the data that's already in the table, so I don't understand the purpose of the SeqNo column.  Create a view that exposes this column maybe but it doesn't need to be maintained.  Otherwise you need to update the whole table every time a row is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand everything, but take a look at this example:

```
DECLARE @OrderDetails TABLE
  ( 
   Order_ID int
  ,Order_Code varchar(10)
  ,Product_Name varchar(15)
  ,Qty int
  )

INSERT  INTO @OrderDetails
        ( Order_ID, Order_Code, Product_Name, Qty)
VALUES  ( 10001, 'OC', 'Ottoman', 10 )
,       ( 10002, 'OC', 'Ottoman', 3 )
,       ( 10003, 'OC', 'Ottoman', 2 )
,       ( 10004, 'OC', 'Ottoman', 2 )
,       ( 10005, 'SF', 'Sofa', 2 )
,       ( 10006, 'SF', 'Sofa', 7 )

;
WITH  abcd
        AS ( SELECT Order_ID
                   ,Order_Code
                   ,Product_Name
                   ,Qty
                   ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Order_Code ) AS [RnkSeq]
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Order_Code ORDER BY Order_ID ) AS [NumSeq]
             FROM   @OrderDetails
           )
  SELECT  Order_ID
         ,Order_Code
         ,Product_Name
         ,Qty
         ,CAST(RnkSeq AS varchar(10)) + CHAR(64 + NumSeq) AS SeqNo
  FROM    abcd
```

Returns

```
Order_ID    Order_Code Product_Name    Qty         SeqNo
----------- ---------- --------------- ----------- -----------
10001       OC         Ottoman         10          1A
10002       OC         Ottoman         3           1B
10003       OC         Ottoman         2           1C
10004       OC         Ottoman         2           1D
10005       SF         Sofa            2           2A
10006       SF         Sofa            7           2B
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

To update and have `1, 1A, 1B..` use:

```
;
WITH  abcd
        AS ( SELECT Order_ID
                   ,Order_Code
                   ,Product_Name
                   ,Qty
                   ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Order_Code ) AS [RnkSeq]
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Order_Code ORDER BY Order_ID ) AS [NumSeq]
             FROM   @OrderDetails
           ),
      efgh
        AS ( SELECT Order_ID
                   ,Order_Code
                   ,Product_Name
                   ,Qty
                   ,CAST(RnkSeq AS varchar(10)) + CHAR(63 + NumSeq) AS [Seq]
             FROM   abcd
           )
  UPDATE  @OrderDetails
  SET     SeqNo = REPLACE(e.Seq,'@','')
  FROM    @OrderDetails AS o
          JOIN efgh AS e ON e.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
```

Beware what happens when you get more than `1, 1A, ... 1Z` different order numbers for Ottomans.

Comment: Damir,
Great. This is what I was looking for but couple of questions. Data in Orderdetails table is already there I need to just update the SeqNo column with this values. And how do I update with 1,1A,1B instead of 1a,1b,1c

Comment: acadia, can you explain why, if you can get the "SeqNo" value in a query, you need to hard-code the value in the table?

Comment: Aaron, I am using the same seq value in many pages in my asp.net application and crystal reports. As you rightly suggested I am going with the view instead of table updates.

Comment: Damir, in the above sample you gave me is there a way we can have seqNo as 1,1A,1B,1C and instead of 2A,2B it should be 1A,1B for each and every code set it should start with 1 thanks for your wonderful help

Comment: use `CHAR(63 + NumSeq)`, that gives `1@, 1A, 1B ...` then use string replace `REPLACE(SomeString,'@','')` as in the example above.